# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while printing a TreeSet

Tags: java, arrays, abstract-class, treelist

I want to create a Treeset for abstract class. When I'm trying to print the value for the [0] in the treeset the output is giving `1` correctly but the output for [1] it is giving error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1`

Can someone please help me resolve this?

```
public abstract class E implements Comparable<E>{
    private int Id;
    private String name;

    public E(int Id, String name) {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    int id;
    public int compareTo(E b) {  
        if(id>b.id){  
            return 1;  
        }else if(id<b.id){  
            return -1;  
        }else{  
        return 0;  
        }  
    }   
    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }   
    public String Name() {
        return name;
    }   
  }
```

Comment: You need to decide which id you want to use, either `empId` or `id`. Setting one and checking the other doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I dont undersatnd. I'm new in using TreeSets. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: See your `Employee` class. You set `empId` in the constructor, but use `id` in `compareTo`. `id` has never been set to anything, so is initialized to 0.

Comment: @MegCullen Note: You may wish to choose another name other than E for your class. You may have seen Comparable<E> or other structures with E or T in the diamond operator, but that doesn't mean the class is literally named "E" or "T." More on that here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your compareTo method inside Employee class you should compare empId, not this int id that you creating and never initializing.

Comment: Using empId instead of id worked. Thank you very much.